# Failed to pass parameter begin with #?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I have a rest Api with spring boot :

```
PageableResult<List<T>> search(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){

        Map<String, String[]> params = request.getParameterMap();
        log.info("params: {}", params);
        return getService().search(params);
    }
```

but when I use postman
[image]

And In service function I have nothing when using code below.

```
String resultat = params.get("resultat");// I have nothing with resultat
```

So what happen with parameter begin by "#" symbol. How to solve it?

Comment: i think/hope, that postman is capable of URL-en/decoding...but it can also be part of the issue.

Comment: If the `resultant` was first key instead of last, you wouldn't be able to see `search`, `pageNumber` and `pageSize` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use `%23` to pass `#` as a character.

[Here](https://www.urlencoder.org/) is a website to convert your keywords into necessary format.

Comment: @YetDev Anything after `#` isn't sent to server side.

Comment: ..he uses postman

Comment: @xerx593 postman doesn't encode the uri and sends it as it is. You can click on preview button to analyze the request.

Comment: ..true, for the uri, the user is responsible, but when using "query-key-value" (form ..as in screenshot) url-encoding is no issue!

Comment: ... https://imgur.com/a/AKzZXNl

Comment: @xerx593 I am using the browser extension of postman and have a different interface, I can't reproduce the same as you.